# PHP for each com uma regra if

Tags: php, foreach, if

Tenho uma tabela que traz resultados de comissões pagas e não pagas.

Quero que ele traga apenas as pagas, ou seja, se `number_format($row->amount_paid,2) = 0` não trazer essa linha.

```
<?php 
    $i=-1;
    foreach($this->rows->rows as $row){?>
        <tr class="sectiontableentry<?php echo ($i%2)+1;?>">
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo empty($row->timestamp) ? '' : date('Y-m-d',$row->timestamp); ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo $row->order_number; ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->order_total,2); ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->commission,2); ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->amount_paid,2);?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->balance,2); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->note; ?>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<?php  }?>
```

Acredito que tenha que usar o if em algum lugar, correto? Mas não sei como.

Comment: `if(number_format($row->amount_paid,2) != 0){ //...código}` não funciona?

Comment: então, minha dúvida é onde colocar o if
coloquei aqui: foreach($this->rows->rows as $row){if(number_format($row->amount_paid,2) != 0){ //...código}}
mas não deu

Comment: Depois do `foreach` e antes do `<tr>` e fecha depois do `</tr>`

Comment: Descupla, deu sim, eu tinha colocado um "}" a menos, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar o `if` dentro do `loop`, antes de qualquer código HTML, condicionando-o:

```
<?php 
  $i=-1;
  foreach($this->rows->rows as $row):
    if (number_format($row->amount_paid,2) != 0):
?>
      <tr class="sectiontableentry<?php echo ($i%2)+1;?>">
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo empty($row->timestamp) ? '' : date('Y-m-d',$row->timestamp); ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo $row->order_number; ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->order_total,2); ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->commission,2); ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->amount_paid,2);?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo number_format($row->balance,2); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->note; ?>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endif;
  endforeach;
?>
```

> **Nota**: O valor da variável `i` não é alterado dentro do laço, acredito que esqueceu de incrementá-lo, provavelmente.